# How to fix Fortran runtime error: End of file?

Tags: fortran

I am trying to read a file called "syerasg.txt" in Fortran90. This text file includes panel data on 91 variables (columns) for 8984 individuals for 16 years (143 744 rows). This variables are divided in 7 groups and this groups are divided in 13 subgroups. I am trying to read this file with the following code:

```
 PROGRAM main
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: p=8984, tf=16, sem=53, emp=7, gap=13
    INTEGER :: r, t, j, m, g, x, i, IOstatus 
    INTEGER, DIMENSION (p,tf,emp) :: yemp
    INTEGER, DIMENSION (p,tf,emp,gap) :: gaps
    OPEN(UNIT=4, FILE='syearsg.txt',STATUS='old') !start gap years 
DO i=1,p 
    DO t=1,tf
        DO j=1,emp 
            IF (j==1) THEN 
                READ(4,*)(gaps(i,t,j,g),g=1,13)            
            ELSE IF (j==2) THEN
                READ(4,*)(gaps(i,t,j,g-13),g=14,26)
            ELSE IF (j==3) THEN 
                READ(4,*)(gaps(i,t,j,g-26),g=27,39)
            ELSE IF (j==4) THEN 
                READ(4,*)(gaps(i,t,j,g-39),g=40,52)
            ELSE IF (j==5) THEN 
                READ(4,*)(gaps(i,t,j,g-52),g=53,65)
            ELSE IF (j==6) THEN 
                READ(4,*)(gaps(i,t,j,g-65),g=66,78)
            ELSE IF (j==7) THEN 
                READ(4,*)(gaps(i,t,j,g-78),g=79,91)
            END IF 
        END DO    
   END DO
END DO
CLOSE(4)
END PROGRAM main
```

When, running the code I get the following message:

> Fortran runtime error: End of file

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome. Please.use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop nest issues `1,006,208` (that is `p*tf*emp`) `read` statements.  It's no surprise that the program runs past the end of a file with only `143,744` lines.  `read` reads the values it is asked to read, then skips to the start of the next line ready for the next `read`.

You might be able to fix your program by fiddling around with *non-advancing* input, ie telling the `read` statements not to skip to the start of the next line.  But it would be easier not to.

From what you write you should only be issuing `p*tf` `read` statements, then reading a single line containing `91` elements, then distributing those elements into `gaps` as your logic demands.

You might revise your code to something like this (untested and not very carefully checked)

```
INTEGER, DIMENSION(91) :: workvec
...    
DO i=1,p 
    DO t=1,tf
       READ(4,*) workvec            
       gaps(i,t,1,1:13) = workvec( 1:13)       
       gaps(i,t,2,1:13) = workvec(14:26)
       ...       
    END DO    
END DO
```